# Add after event listener in configuration

Tags: events, configuration, sencha-touch-2, event-listener

I know it is possible to add listeners to events that fire after the event has fired like this:

```
oDocumentCategories.addAfterListener("activeitemchange", function(oContainer, sValue, oldValue){
    //Do stuff here
});
```

But is it also possible to attach them whilst creating the elements?
Just like this:

```
var oButton = Ext.create("Ext.Button", {
            text: "Button",
            listeners: {
                tap: function(){
                    //Tap event here
                }
            }
        });
```

But only then for an after listener.

**Question**
Is it possible to attach an after event listener whilst creating an element?
Just like the `listeners` configuration property but then for an after event listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var oButton = Ext.create("Ext.Button", {
      text: "Button",
      listeners: {
            tap: {
               fn: function(){
                //Tap event here
               },
               // scope: this,
               // options: {single: true}
               order: 'after'
           }
      }
 });
```

Cheers, Oleg